# How to calculate the number of days in a period?

Tags: java, java-8

For the following `Period` calculation:

```
Period.between(LocalDate.of(2015, 8, 1), LocalDate.of(2015, 9, 2))
```

the result is:

```
P1M1D
```

This is equivalent to 31 days + 1 day = 32 days.

For this `Period`:

```
Period.between(LocalDate.of(2015, 8, 1), LocalDate.of(2015, 10, 2))
```

the result is:

```
P2M1D
```

This is equivalent to: 31 days (in August) + 30 days (in September) + 1 (in October) = 62 days

Is there a method in the `java.time` package which will give the number of days in a `Period`? I can't find one. Not sure if I have overlooked anything or if it is just plain not there.

Comment: Period have a method `long get(TemporalUnit unit)`, TemporalUnit can be ChronoUnit.DAYS

Comment: @cyrbil but that does not do what the OP asks, try it and see.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html):

> To define an amount of time with date-based values (years, months,
>   days), use the `Period` class. The `Period` class provides various get
>   methods, such as `getMonths`, `getDays`, and `getYears`.To present the amount >of time measured in a  single unit of time, such as days, you can use the
>   `ChronoUnit.between` method.
>
> ```
> LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
> LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1);
>
> Period p = Period.between(birthday, today);
> long p2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(birthday, today);
> System.out.println("You are " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() +
>                    " months, and " + p.getDays() +
>                    " days old. (" + p2 + " days total)");
> ```
>
> The code produces output similar to the following:
>
> ```
> You are 53 years, 4 months, and 29 days old. (19508 days total)
> ```

Comment: Why didn't they put that method in `Period` itself?‮

Comment: Thank you. I was using Period.getDays() without knowing that it returns only the days portion.

Comment: @Carcamano (1) Because months have different lengths, so a Period of, say, 1 month 1 day, doesn’t define a specific number of days. It could be 29, 30, 31 or 32. And (2) it’s exactly a quality of `Period` that it counts years, months and days rather than only days. You can have a period in a variable and add it to any `LocalDate` or other date-time object. If you insisted that a `Period` of 1 month 1 day should also define whether that means 29 or 32 days, then the addition would no longer make sense as a general thing to do.

Answer (score 30):

There is no way to do what you ask. The reason is that it is not possible from a `Period` to deduce the actual number of calendar days in the period. A `Period` is not tied to specific dates, once constructed in the way you show, it loses track of the actual calendar dates.

For example your first period represents a period of 1 month and 1 day. But the period does not care which month. It is simply a concept of "a month and a day".

If you need the number of days between two dates you should use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` as Saket Mittal writes.

Comment: Yes, I realised that. I just wanted to know how to recover the lost information so I could calculate the number of days. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

There's a specific object depending at the amount of time you'd like to deal with.
This page [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) is very useful explaining which is best for your scenario.

> The ChronoUnit.between method is useful when you want to measure an amount of time in a single unit of time only, such as days or seconds

```
LocalDate localDateStartDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 06, 10);
LocalDate localDateEndDate = LocalDate.of(2016,06,23);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(localDateStartDate, localDateEndDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

ChronoUnit works fine, but it requires API level 26, if you are still targeting API level 24 like me, I found this alternative which works well:

```
val start = LocalDate.now()
val end = LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)
val totalDays = Duration.between(start.atStartOfDay(), end.atStartOfDay()).toDays()
```

atStartOfDay will convert LocalDate to LocalDateTime, with time set to 00:00, so we can use Duration calculation to get the total days between the dates

Answer (score 0):

You can just use LocalDate `until` method. For example:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().minusYears(1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now();

Long days = startDate.until(endDate, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
System.out.println(days);
```

This produces the following output:

```
365
```