# Java - Count day of month occurrences in an interval of time

Tags: java

I am using Java 8, i need to count how many days we have in an interval having index = x. Example: from 1-1-2019 till 31-1-2019 we have 1 occurrence of Day 1.

I do not want the range of days, just the count of day X
If its the last day of month, i want to count them all example: 30 +30 +31+28

Comment: what do you mean by 1? is it the 1st day of every month?

Comment: Could you share some of the relevant code? What do you mean by "having index = x"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine number of days represented by a time range in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833781/determine-number-of-days-represented-by-a-time-range-in-java)

Comment: how would you want the code to react when given as input the day of 31, and the interval of a whole year? would the answer be 7?

Comment: index means either first of the month, or last day or any day in between. It is a variable.

Comment: So if index is 31 and the range is the whole year, will the answer be 7 or not?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please add your code to the question.

Comment: if its end of month we will count all of them means 12 in a year. I have a way with no loop but its error prone, i am still trying to find the optimal solution. Will post it when done. The first way was to get the first and then the last occurrences and then  using the Java 8 months.between. But the occurrences must be within the range, and this does not cover the last day of month dilemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public long getNumberOfDayOfMonthBetweenDates(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, int dayOfMonth) {
    long result = -1;
    if (startDate != null && endDate != null && dayOfMonth > 0 && dayOfMonth < 32) {
        result = 0;
        LocalDate startDay = getDayInCurrentMonth(startDate, dayOfMonth);
        // add one day as end date is exclusive
        // add + 1 to cover higher possibilities (month and a half or half month or so)
        long totalMonths = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate.plusDays(1)) + 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalMonths; i++) {
            if ((!startDay.isBefore(startDate) && startDay.isBefore(endDate)) || startDay.equals(startDate) || startDay.equals(endDate)) {
                result++;
            }
            startDay = getDayInCurrentMonth(startDay.plusMonths(1), dayOfMonth);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private LocalDate getDayInCurrentMonth(LocalDate startDate, int dayOfMonth) {
    LocalDate dayOfThisMonth;
    try {
        dayOfThisMonth = startDate.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        // handle cases where current month does not contain the given day (example 30 in Feb)
        dayOfThisMonth = startDate.withDayOfMonth(startDate.lengthOfMonth());
    }
    return dayOfThisMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this method:

```
public static int getDateCount(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, final int index) {
        long numOfDaysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(numOfDaysBetween)
                .mapToObj(i -> startDate.plusDays(i))
                .filter(i -> i.getDayOfMonth() == index)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).size();
    }
```

usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2019,1,1);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2019,1,31);
        int index=1;

        System.out.println(getDateCount(startDate,endDate,index));
    }
```

output:

> 1

Here i first calculated days between two dates then extracted all days occuring between these dates then filtered them to desired day e.g 1 in that case.

**Note :** that might not be the best and effective solution

Comment: using parallel stream can improve performance but i am also trying to achieve it with some other possible way, as soon as i figure it out i will update it here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the java.time API provides methods to directly do this, but you can always loop through all the dates between the start and end check them one by one.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 31);
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
System.out.println(daysBetween);
// you might want to use a parallel stream. It might speed things up a little
long count = LongStream.range(0, daysBetween + 1)
                 .mapToObj(start::plusDays)
                 .filter(x -> x.getDayOfMonth() == index)
                 .count();
System.out.println(count);
```

There is a special case for the last day of the month, you need:

```
.filter(x -> x.equals(x.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())))
```

Comment: anyway to skip the loop and the stream for better performance?

Comment: As I said, you could use a parallel stream, but other than that, I don't think so. @user666

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2019, 3, 31);
    long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);

    int index = 1;
    int count = 0;
    start = start.minusDays(1);
    for(int i = 0; i <= daysBetween; i++){
        start = start.plusDays(1);
        if (start.getDayOfMonth() == index) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

finding days in-between using:

`Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
int days = d.getDays();`

finding specific day was there or not, suppose `11th of month.`

`(startDay + days)` contains the day you require something like that.