# Java Period Between Calendar

Tags: java, mysql, period

For a Java program, I need a Timeperiod from 2 Dates but i get Errors with the Period.Class.

I tried to get the TimePeriod with Period.between

```
     Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.JANUARY,1);
     Calendar myPeriod = new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.MARCH, 1);
     Period prd = Period.between(myCalendar, myPeriod);
     return prd.getTime();
```

I used to return `myCalendar.getTime();`
Now I need the "Period" of `myCalendar` and `myPeriod`.

Thank you.

Comment: What errors do you get? The signature of the method `between` shows that it expects LocalDates, not Calendar

Comment: The method between(LocalDate, LocalDate) in the type Period is not applicable for the arguments (Calendar, Calendar)  for the Error in between

and

The method getTime() is undefined for the type Period  on .getTime

Comment: You can read [how to convert calendar to LocalDate](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-between-old-date-and-calendar-object-with-the-new-java-8-date-time/) or use the other factory methods of LocalDate.

Comment: @DavidKhano As the compiler states, `between()` expects arguments of type `LocalDate` not `Calender`. Also, there is not `getTime()` method in `Period` class [for reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)

Comment: @DavidKhano please [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833582/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-in-a-period) to understand how period works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, the `Period` accepts 2 `LocalDate` parameters (read more about it in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)).

This is the code if you still need the conversion from `Calendar` to `LocalDate`:

```
Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.JANUARY,1);
Calendar myPeriod = new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.MARCH, 1);
LocalDate start = Instant.ofEpochMilli(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate end = Instant.ofEpochMilli(myPeriod.getTimeInMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Otherwise, just create the 2 `LocalDate` variables directly:

```
 LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 1);
 LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.MARCH, 1);
```

And then calculate the period between them:

```
Period prd = Period.between(start, end);
System.out.println(prd.toString()); //P2M
```