# Return ISO-8601 time format in days from Epoch time in Java

Tags: java, time, epoch

I have some Java code which returns the ISO-8601 time format from a given epoch time.

```
public String getISO8601(String epochTime) {
    long epoch = Long.parseLong(epochTs);
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    LocalDate then = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch).atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    Period diff = Period.between(then, today);
    return diff.toString();
}
```

When I pass epochTime to it: `1512259200000`

This epoch time is: **Sun 2017-12-03 00:00:00**

So the method getISO8601 will return: `P1Y`

This is great! But is there any way I can make sure it will always and only return in days... for example: **P365D** (instead of: P1Y)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the number of days in a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833582/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-in-a-period)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately `Period` doesn't allow the units to be specified, but you can use the `until` method to handle this, specifying you want the difference in days:

```
public static Period getPeriodInDaysBetween(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    int days = (int) from.until(to, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    return Period.ofDays(days);
}
```

Use that instead of `Period.between` and it'll do what you want, I believe.

(The first line is equivalent to the `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2)` in MS90's answer. Use whichever you find more readable.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take a look at following code:

```
   public static long countDays(LocalDate date1, LocalDate date2) {

        long daysInAPeriod = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
        return daysInAPeriod;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Period has a getDays method which returns an int number of days in the Period.

Comment: When i do `return Period.between(then, today).getDays();` it returns: 0, instead of 365D