# Get total days from Period

Tags: java, java-time, period

I have `Period` object which comes from api. I have to calculate total days it contains. I found many answers how to get days between two dates, but no one answers how I can get total days exactly from `Period` object.

E.g:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate end = LocalDate.now().plusYears(1);

Period period = Period.between(start, end);
```

I have only the last object with name `period` and i have to get `365` days from it.

`getDays()` returns only days count within one month. And I don't have two dates objects. Only period.

Comment: What about [`Period.getDays()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getDays--)? Can you show us your code that calculates the total days?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Comment: I have to get TOTAL days.

Comment: @HusamBdr again, this question answers how to get days, months and years in period. but I have to get TOTAL days from it. and i don't have these dates. only period

Comment: @Squeez HusamBdr's the critical answer from HusamBdr's link is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30833785/424903). You can't will the Period class into being what you want it to be, it simply isn't.

Comment: @Gimby oh, okay, thank you

Comment: @Squeez What do you mean by *TOTAL days*? The amount of days in a period?

Comment: @deHaar yes. guys answered that that's not possible

Comment: @Squeez Yes, I have seen that... And the method I suggested does not do that... Sorry...

Comment: @deHaar no problem. thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna read up on the [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getDays--) Java API Documentation. 
Period represents the time duration in this format, "2 years, 3 months and 4 days"
For your case above, its exactly 1 year, 0 Months and 0 days. 
When you do a get Days, it will show you 0 days.

Try with an end date of `LocalDate end = LocalDate.now().minusDays(398);`
The getYears(), getMonths(), getDays() each returns its own value. ;)

Since you already have a Period object, you can do a function to get the number of days from a Period Object using the getYears, getMonths and getDays() methods then sum them together.

The [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object might help with that.

Answer (score -1):

did you tried import java.time package and use Period class? if you didn't, here's a little help for it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html

Comment: OP obviously did...