# Java Period return wrong number of days between 2 dates

Tags: java, java-time

i have the following code to calculate the difference of days between 2 days `01/09/2023 and 02/10/2023` the excpected result is 31 days but the code return 1 days.

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.of(2023, 9, 1);
LocalDate to = LocalDate.of(2023, 10, 02);

Period period = Period.between(from, to);

System.out.print(period.getYears() + " years,");
System.out.print(period.getMonths() + " months,");
System.out.print(period.getDays() + " days");
```

output :

```
0 years,1 months,1 days
```

can anyone tell me what's the wrong with my code

Comment: Why isn't it correct? It's exactly 1 month and 1 day.

Comment: is 1 month 1 day correct? How this could be wrong

Comment: It's 1 day and 1 month. If you want the amount of days between `from` and `to`, you're looking for `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to);`

Comment: thanks @Rouge, it's exaclty what im looking for. can you put it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: basically you want to [Calculate days between two Dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27005861/85421) or [How to calculate the number of days in a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30833582/85421)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parts of a Period are *additive*: The period between your two dates is 1 month **and** 1 day.

---

To calculate the period of days between LocalDates, use [`until()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-):

```
long daysBetween = from.until(to, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

or the convenience method [between()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-):

```
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to);
```